# Domain pointing from A -> B and B-A

Tags: dns, cross-domain

I am trying to redirect domains among each other. For example

a) Domain A -> B
b) Domain B -> A

Domain A and B are on different hosts and have different name servers. What is the easiest way without migrating full sites ? I am aware i can point Domain A -> B , however if i try to point Domain B -> A after, it will go in an infinite loop.

I am not an expert in updating Cname records but willing to look into it if that is the only choice.

Any help would be wonderful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the appropriate A records in the authoritative name servers.
Records look like this:

```
Aserver     A       192.134.56.78
Bserver     A       192.134.56.79
```

Some links to read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727018.aspx
https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/introduction-to-dns-records